# i have a list of roll no and gr no and i want to validate whether there are duplicate roll nos or gr no

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFD8C.png)I searched for this validation but i got only validations for text field compairng.
how to give the validation on list of roll nos and gr nos.
like I have a list of students in jsp besides each student I have 2 text boxes for gr no and rollno .I want to validate that no one enters duplicate gr no or rollno

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking. If you need help with a particular piece of code, try including a snippet. I'm not sure what you mean by "roll no" or "gr no"

Comment: i'hav added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

> that no one enters duplicate gr no or rollno

Such validation needs to be done server side.

## More

Look at xhrs, since you tagged jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/